# Convert bmp to 256 colors

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I need to reduce a 32bit bmp to a maximum of 256 colors, either manually or through some built in .net functionality. I haven't managed to find any info on how to do it. Could someone offer some pointers please.

Edit: To clarify, I don't really just want to convert the 32 bit bmp to an 8 bit bmp. I want to map the input bmp to a standard 256 color palette, so I know it will display ok on a portable device. A kind of "make web safe" function.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous enough on its own let alone when considering your comment on the only answer, ie "am talking about single colors, also I am not talking about conversion but rather about a color-generator or a color-list." You should try better explaining what you're after.

Comment: It's not my comment. And this question is 4 years old. Thanks for the downvote though.